# krb5.keytab entries need to have uppercase service type

Tags: kerberos, sssd

I'm encountering an issue with the keytab entries that are automatically created when I join a Linux server to an Active Directory domain. First, my process:

1. Install the needed Linux packages `yum install realmd pam sssd adcli oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir samba-common-tools krb5-workstation`
2. Create Computer object in Active Directory and add the relevant SPN entries (servicePrincipalName)
3. Perform the domain join with `realm join -v EXAMPLE.COM -U domainUser`

During the join, the process automatically creates a krb5.keytab file with entries that directly match the Computer object's SPN entries.  So if the SPN had an entry of ServerName@example.com, the join process creates a keytab entry of ServerName@example.com.  **The problem is** if the SPN has a capitalized service type included in the name, the keytab generation process doesn't respect the service type case but instead forces the keytab entry to have a lowercase service type. So if the SPN is **HTTP**/ServerName@example.com, then the keytab generator forces it to be **http**/ServerName@example.com, during the domain join process. In order for the application I'm using to work, these need to match (both be uppercase).

With my objective being to have a keytab entry that matches the SPN (uppercase service type), from what I can think of, I have two options

1. Fix the `realm join` process to keep the same case for the service type, or
2. Create my own keytab entry into the keytab file

I'm having problems with both options.  For the first option, I'm not able to find anything with the join process that can be changed.  For the second option, I've found 2 possible applications I could use in order to create my own entry.  These applications are kadmin & ktutil.  The kadmin gives me an error of "required KADM5 principal missing..." (of which I can't figure out how to fix).  And the ktutil option would work, except that it requires the same password be applied to this new keytab entry, that is used by the other keytab entries; however, this password is managed by Active Directory and is not obtainable.

Has anyone else run into this before and have a solution on how to keep a keytab entry's service type uppercase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that you *shouldn't* be adding these SPNs to the host's keytab (computer account) in the first place. Services such as Samba (cifs) or SSH (host) can continue to use it, but everything else (HTTP, imap, etc.) should have their own independent keys *in their own keytab files.* (Broadly, if the service isn't in AD's default "service aliases" list for 'host', then it shouldn't be sharing the computer account.)

The usual way to create additional principals (not associated to the computer account) in Active Directory is to create a *user* account with a randomized password and assign it the SPNs needed. Active Directory does not use the MIT kadmin protocol; its management is done through LDAP – the only way to create Kerberos principals is the `servicePrincipalName` LDAP attribute that you've already found. (But don't forget to set `msDS-SupportedEncryptionTypes` as well!)

With the Samba tools, `samba-tool spn add` and `samba-tool domain exportkeytab` could be used to achieve this; you could also do it using `ktutil` to hand-craft a keytab, or even from Windows using RSAT and `ktpass.exe`.

Something like this should work:

```
samba-tool user create HTTP-foo --random-password
samba-tool user setexpiry HTTP-foo --noexpiry
samba-tool spn add HTTP/foo.example.com HTTP-foo
net ads enctypes set HTTP-foo 24
samba-tool domain exportkeytab HTTP.keytab --principal=HTTP/foo.example.com
```

Comment: The application is Microsoft SCOM. It's actually the /etc/opt/omi/ssl/omi.keytab file.  I had initially thought this was just a copy of krb5.keytab.  When I try to deploy a SCOM agent, the install throws an Access Denied error. The omiserver.log file says the event was "Client Authorization Failed... Request ticket server HTTP/ServerName.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM"; however, SCOM can't authenticate with lowercase "http", since there's no keytab entry for it.  If I could add an entry for "HTTP", it might work.  Thanks for your insights, guidance, and options to try!! I'll report back my results

Comment: Got it! Although I don't know if this has any consequences. 1) use realm join to join to domain and have background configurations automatically generated, 2) use "adcli join --show-password" to re-join to the domain, but this time it displays the password for the computer object, 3) use ktutil to add an entry for the "HTTP" key, using the computer password when prompted for the user account password.  SCOM can now connect successfully.  Thanks again for your insights!